# React Table Filtering - Trouble with accessors that are returning values

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

I am using React Table 7.6.x.

I've created column filters for my React Table.

If I try to filter a column where I am using a return statement in the accessor to return a Link Component, the filter does not work. Oddly - the filter works as expected if I use a formatting function in the accessor like:

```
accessor: (d) => {
      return d.incidentStartDate ? formatDateMDY(d.incidentStartDate) : "";
    },
```

but doing this:

```
 accessor: (d) => {
      return <Link to={{ pathname: `/enforcements/watersystems/${d.systemId}` }}>UTAH{d.altId}</Link>;
    }
```

breaks the filter.

Is there a way I can account for this in the filter creation or should I be writing the column differently?

FILTER NOT WORKING - COLUMN ATTRIBUTES USING A RETURN

```
 {
    Header: "Incident #",
    id: "incidentNumber",
    accessor: (d) => {
      return (
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: `/enforcements/watersystem/${d.systemId}/${d.incidentNumber}`,
            state: { incident: d }
          }}
        >
          {d.incidentNumber}
        </Link>
      );
    },
    width: 90
  },
```

FILTER WORKS IF I CHANGE HEADING TO:

```
 {
    Header: "Incident #",
    id: "incidentNumber",
    accessor: "incidentNumber",
    width: 90
  },
```

COLUMN FILTER CODE

```
const DefaultColumnFilter = ({ column: { filterValue, preFilteredRows, setFilter } }) => {
  return (
    <InputGroup size="sm" className="mb-3 mt-3">
      <FormControl
        aria-label="Small"
        aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
        value={filterValue || ""}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFilter(e.target.value || undefined);
        }}
        placeholder={"Search ..."}
      />
    </InputGroup>
  );
};
```

DEFAULT COLUMN STATEMENT

```
 const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      Filter: DefaultColumnFilter,
      defaultFilters: true,
      minWidth: 30,
      width: 150,
      maxWidth: 500
    }),
    []
  );
```

UPDATE: If I change the column to use `Cell` instead of `accessor` the filter box just disappears.

```
  {
    Header: "Incident #",
    id: "incidentNumber",
    //accessor: "incidentNumber",
    Cell: ({ row }) => {
      return (
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: `/enforcements/watersystem/${row.original.systemId}/${row.original.incidentNumber}`,
            state: { incident: row.original }
          }}
        >
          {row.original.incidentNumber}
        </Link>
      );
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get rid of this issue by using the `Cell` attribute for the ROW element and `accessor` for the filtered column value as below.

```
{
Header: "Incident #",
accessor: "incidentNumber",
Cell: ({ row }) => {
  return (
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: `/enforcements/watersystem/${row.original.systemId}/${row.original.incidentNumber}`,
        state: { incident: row.original }
      }}
    >
      {row.original.incidentNumber}
    </Link>
  );
},
```